# Splitting short exact sequence of space groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I want to prove the following:

Assume we have two space groups $G,G^\prime \subseteq \text{Euc}(V) \subseteq \text{Aff}(V)$ which are affinely equivalent, $G \sim G^\prime, \; \text{ i.e. }\; \exists\, (\xi,a)\in \text{Aff}(V)\,:\; (\xi,a)\,G\,(\xi,a)^{-1} = G^\prime $.

Now define

$T(G) := G \cap \{(\tau,\mathbb{1}\;|\; \tau\in V)\}$ the normal subgroup and $P(G) := \{a\in O(V) \;|\; (\tau,a)\in G \text{ for some $\tau \in V$} \}$ the point group of $G$

(correspondingly for $G^\prime$).

The claim is that if the short exact sequence

$1 \longrightarrow T(G) \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow P(G) \longrightarrow 1$

splits, then so does the corresponding sequence for $G^\prime$.

I have already proven, that for the commuting diagram with short exact rows

$1 \longrightarrow G_1 \longrightarrow G_2 \longrightarrow G_3 \longrightarrow 1$

$\quad \quad \;\;\:\downarrow \quad \quad \;\;\;\downarrow \quad \quad \;\;\downarrow$

$1 \longrightarrow H_1 \longrightarrow H_2 \longrightarrow H_3 \longrightarrow 1$

with groups $G_i,H_i$ and homomorphisms

$\varphi_i: \; G_i \rightarrow G_{i+1}$,

$\psi_i: \; H_i \rightarrow H_{i+1}$,

$f_i: G_i \rightarrow H_{i}$,

it holds that

$f_1,f_3 $ injective $\Rightarrow\; f_2$ injective,

$f_1,f_3 $ surjective $\Rightarrow\; f_2$ surjective.

I'm not sure how to proceed here. I think that if I find isomorphisms $T(G)\rightarrow T(G^\prime)$ and $P(G) \rightarrow P(G^\prime)$, I'm done, since then I can find all needed inverses easily from the (assumed) inverses of the sequence for $G$. I'm also not sure how I could possibly use what I have proven already, because the isomorphism from $G$ to $G^\prime$ is just conjucation (or am I mistaken here?). However, I'm not a specialist on homological algebra, but merely a physics undergrad.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I have thought about it a bit more, and have come to the conclusion that it suffices to find an isomorphism $\beta\,:\;P(G)\longrightarrow P(G^\prime)$. Let's give a name, i.e. $\theta\,:\; G\longrightarrow P(G)$. The sequence for $G$ splits, iff there exists $u\,:\;P(G)\longrightarrow G$ with $u\circ \theta = \mathbb{1}_G$ (by definition, right?). So if we assume $u$ splits the sequence for $G$, and we find two isomorphisms $\alpha\,:\;G\longrightarrow G^\prime$ and $\beta\,:\; P(G)\longrightarrow P(G^\prime)$, then $\alpha\circ u \circ \beta^{-1}\,:\;P(G^\prime) \longrightarrow G^\prime$ splits the sequence for $G^\prime$.
Is this correct?

The isomorphism $\alpha$ exists by assumption, let's say $(g,a)\mapsto (\xi,b)(g,a)(\xi,b)^{-1}$. For the isomorphism $\beta$, I found $a \mapsto bab^{-1}$, where $b$ is the same as in $\alpha$. Then $\beta^{-1}(q) = b^{-1}qb$, and if all this is true i'm done. Looks good to me, what do you think? The remaining problem is now proving that the resulting map indeed splits the $G^\prime$ sequence, and I have no idea how to go about this, because nothing about the map $G^\prime \longrightarrow P(G^\prime)$ is known. I feel that I should prove that the diagram is commutative, or do I get this for free from somewhere?

Comment: I have edited my old answer to fill it out into a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you making use of the conjugation $(\xi,a)\,G\,(\xi,a)^{-1} = G^\prime$? That's what gives the isomorphism from $G$ to $G'$, and it would be a good guess that this isomorphism takes $T(G)$ to $T(G')$ and induces an isomorphism of quotient groups $P(G)=G/T(G) \to P(G')=G'/T(G')$.

**Edited much later:**

They key fact needed is that the translation subgroup $T(V) \subset Aff(V)$ is a normal subgroup of $Aff(V)$. So if $A : V \to V$ is an affine transformation and $AGA^{-1}=G'$ then 
$$A \, T(G) \, A^{-1} = A  \,(G \cap T(V))  \, A^{-1} = (A G A^{-1}) \cap (A \, T(V)  \, A^{-1}) = G' \cap T(V) = T(G')
$$
Let me use $i_A : G \to G'$ to denote the isomorphism defined by conjugating with $A$, that is, $i_A(g) \mapsto AgA^{-1}$.

Lemma: If $i:G \to G'$ is an isomorphism, if $N \subset G$ is normal, and if $N'=i(N) \subset G'$ is normal, then $i$ induces an isomorphim $i_* : G/N \to G'/N'$. This is an immediate consequence of applying the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) to the composed homomorphism $G \xrightarrow{i} G' \mapsto G'/N'$ whose kernel is clearly $N$.

Lemma: A short exact sequence $1 \to N \to G \to Q \to 1$ splits if and only if there exists a retracting homomorphism $r:G \to G$ onto some subgroup of $G$ such that $N = Ker(r)$. Both directions of the "if and only if" are consequences of applying the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem). For the "if" direction one composes the isomorphisms $Q \approx G/N \approx image(r)$ to get the splitting map, and for the "only if" direction, given a splitting map $s:Q\to G$, one composes the maps $G \to Q \xrightarrow{s} G$ to get the retraction.

(By the way, the statement of the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) on that Wikipedia link is rather lazy. The theorem gives you more than just the abstract existence of an isomorphism. By tracing through the proof you get a very particular isomorphism, namely the induced map of the given homomorphism. This is needed in the above applications of the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem)).

So, putting this all together, suppose that $G'$ splits, so there is a retracting homomorphism $G' \xrightarrow{r'} G'$ whose kernel is $T(G')$ ($image(r')$ is of course equal to the image of the splitting $P(G') \to G'$, but we don't need to use that fact at this stage). Define a homomorphism of $G$ as follows:
$$r: G \xrightarrow{i_A} G' \xrightarrow{r'} G' \xrightarrow{i_A^{-1}} G
$$
Tracing through this, one sees that $r$ is a retraction, and using that $T(G') = Ker(r')$ and $i_A(T(G))=T(G')$ one sees that $T(G)=Ker(r)$. Therefore $G$ splits.

Comment: From a quick calculation I did, it looks like you are right, conjugation seems to be an isomorphism $T(G)\rightarrow T(G^\prime)$ aswell. Now I'm stuck at the point of finding the induced isomorphisom between the quotients, any idea how this could work?

Comment: Just use one of the standard theorems of group theory. If you have an isomorphism between two groups $f:G \to G'$, and if the isomorphism takes a normal subgroup $N$ to a normal subgroup $N'$, then the induced map $G/N \to G'/N'$ that takes $gN$ to $f(g)N'$ is a well-defined isomorphism.

Comment: is it essential that the homomorphism $r$ is a retraction? I don't see where that's used in the proof. I assume a retraction is a homomorphism $r:G\rightarrow H\leq G$ with the restriction of r on $H$ being the identity. Where is the last part of this needed?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the proof of the second lemma. How do you verify that $Q\rightarrow G/N \rightarrow \text{Im } r \rightarrow Q = Id_Q$? Or is this clear because $\text{Im }r$ is isomorphic to $Q$?

Comment: @PascalEngeler: The isomorphisms $G/N \to Q$ and $G/N \to \text{image}(r)$ are induced, respectively, by the surjection $G \to Q$, and the retraction $r$ (this is the kind of information that is missing from a lazy statement of the First Isomorphism Theorem). So if you define the splitting homomorphism by composing the inverse of the isomorphism $G/N \to Q$ followed by the isomorphism $G/N \to \text{Im}(r)$, it will follow with a bit of thought regarding cosets of $N$ that the composition you write down is indeed $\text{Id}_Q$.

Comment: @PascalEngeler: The way that the retraction is used is that each coset $gN$ (i.e. each element of $G/N$) contains exactly one element $g' \in \text{image}(r)$, and the image of $gN$ under $r$ is equal to $g'$.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help and thorough explanations!